# ¿Cómo separar apellidos que estén en la misma columna? en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla llamada pruebas:
[image: Imagen 1]

Si observan, algunos registros tienen `apellidopaterno` y `apellidomaterno`, pero otras tienen los dos apellidos en la misma columna(`apellidopaterno`), y `apellidomaterno` está en `null`.
Quiero hacer que independientemente, si el usuario ingresa el apellido paterno y el apellido materno correctamente en columnas separadas, o ingresa los dos apellidos en la columna `apellidopaterno`, que se puedan separar en `apellidopaterno` y `apellidomaterno`.
Hice este código:

```
select
(split_part(nombre,' ',1)||' '||
split_part(nombre,' ',2)||' '||
split_part(nombre,' ',3))as nombres,
split_part(apellidopaterno,' ',1),
split_part(apellidopaterno,' ',2),
split_part(apellidomaterno,' ',1)
from prueba
```

El problema es que me da esta tabla(imagen 2)

[image: Imagen2]

Yo quiero que siempre se pueda mostrar el apellido paterno en la columna `apellidopaterno`, y el apellido materno en la columna `apellidomaterno`, y que nunca quede en `null` ninguno. Alguna idea, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Si la columna `apellidopaterno` nunca va a estar vacía podrías conseguir lo que buscas haciendo un `CONCAT` de las ultimas 2 columnas del select, para que se muestren en una misma columna:

```
select
(split_part(nombre,' ',1)||' '||
split_part(nombre,' ',2)||' '||
split_part(nombre,' ',3))as nombres,
split_part(apellidopaterno,' ',1),
concat(split_part(apellidopaterno,' ',2),
split_part(apellidomaterno,' ',1))
from prueba
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ves las pruebas hechas en el siguiente [enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ef277/3).